# Learning jython string manipulation

Tags: jython

I'm learning jython, and I want to see how to replace the suffix of a string.
For example, I have string:

```
com.foo.ear
```

and I want to replace the suffix to get:

```
com.foo.war
```

I cannot get replace or re.sub to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention `re.sub`; here's one way to use that:

```
import re
re.sub('.ear$','.war','com.foo.ear')
# -> 'com.foo.war'
```

The `$` matches the end of the string.

Using `replace` would be even simpler:

```
'com.foo.ear'.replace('ear','war')
# -> 'com.foo.war'
```

Edit:
And since that looks like a path, you may want to look into using [`os.path.splitext`](http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/Scripting.html#manipulating-files):

```
'{0}{1}'.format(os.path.splitext('com.foo.ear')[0],'.war')
# -> 'com.foo.war'
```